# change weather icon from json in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i have in my computer icons for weather condition

i want to change default icons by my icons what can i do

in json file there is variable for example : "icon":"partlycloudy"

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<body>
<img id='wicon'><img>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var state = 'CA';
 var city = 'San_Francisco';
 var URL = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/102376e7c0e1c995/geolookup/conditions/q/' + state + '/' + city + '.json';
$.ajax({ url : URL, 
dataType : "jsonp", 
success : function(parsed_json) { 
var location = parsed_json['current_observation']['display_location']['full']; 
var temp = parsed_json['current_observation']['temperature_string'];
var wicon = parsed_json['current_observation']['icon_url'];
</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

i want to change the weather condition icon
by adding variable into the link like this

http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/'; + icon variable + '.gif

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var state = 'CA';
 var city = 'San_Francisco';
 var URL = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/102376e7c0e1c995/geolookup/conditions/q/' + state + '/' + city + '.json';
$.ajax({ url : URL, 
dataType : "jsonp", 
success : function(parsed_json) { 
var location = parsed_json['current_observation']['display_location']['full']; 
var temp = parsed_json['current_observation']['temperature_string'];
var wicon = parsed_json['current_observation']['icon_url'];
var humidity = parsed_json['current_observation']['relative_humidity'];
var wind = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_string'];
var pressure = parsed_json['current_observation']['pressure_mb'];
var visibility = parsed_json['current_observation']['visibility_km'];
var weicon = parsed_json['current_observation']['icon'];
$("#meteo").text(temp);
$( '<img>' ).attr( 'src', wicon ).appendTo( '#wicon' );
$("#location").text(location);
$("#humidity").text(humidity);
$("#wind").text(wind);
$("#pressure").text(pressure);
$("#visibility").text(visibility);
} }); });
```

the var wicon is the link of weather icon 
and the var weicon is name of the icon

please help

Comment: so what you're trying to do is change the src for the img tag to the new src?

Answer (score 0):

just add this to the success function

```
\\ get the element that we will change
var pic = document.getElementById('wicon');
\\ update the img to new src
pic.src = wicon
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you sould change your code to this 
and thats deppend on what the wicon value could be

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var state = 'CA';
        var city = 'San_Francisco';
        var URL = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/102376e7c0e1c995/geolookup/conditions/q/' + state + '/' + city + '.json';
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(parsed_json) {
                var location = parsed_json['current_observation']['display_location']['full'];
                var temp = parsed_json['current_observation']['temperature_string'];
                var wicon = parsed_json['current_observation']['icon_url'];

                if(wicon !=null) {
                    $("#icoImg").attr("src", wicon);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    );
            </script>


<body>

    <img id="icoImg" src="#"/>
</body>
```

Comment: i want to change the source of icons ?

Comment: i want a variable in img link like this
http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/' + icon variable + '.gif

Comment: i couldnt understand would please give me details